# Why $f_{X,Y,X+Y}(x,y,t)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathbb 1_{\{X+Y=t\}}$?

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim Poisson(\lambda )$ and $Y\sim Poisson(\mu)$ independent. We denote $f_{X,Y,X+Y}$ the conjoint density function. Why $$f_{X,Y,X+Y}(x,y,t)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathbb 1_{X+Y=t}\ \ ?$$

In some sense, I agree (just to compare with discret random variable, if $x+y\neq t$, then $$\mathbb P(X=x,Y=x,X+Y=t)=0.$$
But even in this case, I'm not so sure why $$\mathbb P(X=x,Y=y,X+Y=t)=\mathbb P(X=x,Y=y)$$
when $x+y=t$. So I don't really see how to make the argument precise. Any idea ? (and I didn't use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are poisson and independent, so maybe it's necessary...)

Comment: This should work for any continuous random variables $X,Y$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Thank you. Do you know how to prove it rigorously ? I tried to show $\mathbb P(X\in A,Y\in B,X+Y\in C)=\mathbb P(X\in A,Y\in B)\mathbb 1_{\{X+Y\in C\}}$, but I can't prove it...

Comment: It only works if the joint density with respect to the Lebesgue measure is assumed to be continuous. In that case, let $x+y\neq t$. Then there exists a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $$\mathsf P_{X,Y,X+Y}([x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon]\times[y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon]\times[t-\varepsilon,t+\varepsilon])=0$$ (why?) Then $$\int_{[x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon]\times[y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon]\times[t-\varepsilon,t+\varepsilon]} f = 0.$$ Now conclude $f(x,y,t)=0$. Please tell me if you want further hints

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: You should write it as an answer :-)